# Creating narrated slideshow from multiple images and sound files

Tags: bash, audio, video, ffmpeg

I have a set of slides in jpg format (s-00.jpg, s-01.jpg, ...) and a set of audio files in mp3 format (a-00.mp3, a-01.mp3, ...).

I would like to create an mp4 with a narrated slideshow from this:

- s-00.jpg shows while a-00.mp3 play
- s-01.jpg shows while a-01.mp3 plays
- ...

I'm sure this is relatively trivial with ffmpeg, but I struggle with the syntax. All I managed to find out so far is that I can make a video from the images with

```
ffmpeg -i s-%02d.jpg slideshow.mp4
```

I found lots of examples how to add one mp3 file to the whole slide show, but could not find anything that adds a different mp3 to each slide.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: just a thought but due to all your moving parts, u may consider 2 steps . For all slides get the audio and ffmpeg merge those 2  , repeat for all slides .. Part 2 is more difficult . Its the concat filter that iterates / concats all the discreet vids to comprise final output

Comment: Thanks, @RobertRowntree - I think I would have kept on searching for days instead of doing that simple extra step...

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Robert in the comment above, I found the answer. I wrote a bash script that does this rather than trying to come up with an overcomplex ffmpeg solution:

```
# Create one video per slide
for file in *.mp3 
do
    number=$(echo $file | cut -f 1 -d '.')
    ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -i $number.jpg -i tmp-$file -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -b:a 192k -vf format=yuv420p -shortest $number.mp4


    echo "file '$number.mp4'" >> files.txt
done

# Merge videos
ffmpeg -y -f concat -safe 0 -i files.txt -movflags +faststart -c copy output.mp4


# Clean up
mv output.mp4 output.do_not_delete
rm *.mp4
mv output.do_not_delete output.mp4
rm files.txt
```

Comment: Recommend adding `-vf format=yuv420p` to first `ffmpeg` command so output is playable by non-FFmpeg based players, and `-movflags +faststart` to second command if the output is to be watched via progressive download. Also, quote your variables so it doesn't break on file names with spaces (see shellcheck.net). If you want to optimize out the `cut` command use parameter expansion to deal with the extension.

Comment: Thanks! Have amended this - see above

Comment: `-movflags +faststart` is an output option, so it should be moved to be before the output file, not before the input.

Comment: That explains why it broke... I will never understand ffmpeg. Thanks!